# Automate creation of an at job using expect

Tags: expect, at

I am trying to write a script that will take time and process-name and pass them to at to schedule the job. I cannot send the EOT.

```
    #! /usr/bin/expect
    # Usage: setupkill.exp time process.
    # press ctrl-D to finish the at command.

    set time [lindex $argv 0]
    set process [lindex $argv 1]

    spawn at $time
    expect "at>"
    send "/home/jagan/p/killprocess $process\r";
    expect "at>"
    send "^D";

    interact
```

This script aims to kill a specific process at a given time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You send ctrl-D like this: `send "\004"`

- http://wiki.tcl.tk/3038
- http://expect.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#q54

Answer (score 3):

You could use a plain shell script:

```sh
#! /bin/sh
# Usage: setupkill.sh time process.
echo /home/jagan/p/killprocess "$2" | at "$1"
```

(Sorry, I don't know `expect` so this is just a simple workaround.)

Comment: Not just a workaround, not using expect is the right answer here. But note that in general, what you pass to `at` will need to have an extra layer of quoting, since what you echo is a shell script.